# How to evaluate $\int_T\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \, dx \, dy$

Tags: integration

I need to calculate the value of the integral:
$$\int_T\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \, dx \, dy$$ where $T=\{(x,y) : x\in[-2,2], x^2<y<4\}$.

Specifically, I need to know how to set integration extremes.

Comment: $\int_{-2}^2 dx \int_{x^2}^4 dy \frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $

Answer (score 1):

The integration extremes are very easy to find:

$$T = \{(x, y): x \in [-2, 2], x^2 < y < 4\}$$

clearly tells you that $-2 \leq x \leq 2$. Therefore $x$ will range from $-2$ to $2$. Now imagine that $x$ is fixed at $x_0$. At that point, $x_0^2 \leq y \leq 4$. This means the integral becomes

$$\int_T\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \, dx \, dy = \int_{-2}^{2}\int_{x^2}^{4} \frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \, dy \, dx$$

**i.e.** $y$'s extremes must come after $x$'s because the values for $y$ depend on the value of $x$.

Comment: Your last statement is very confusing: (all that follows i.e.)

Comment: @amWhy would you say it is better now?

Answer (score 1):

The integration limits are
$$\int_{-2}^2\int_{x^2}^4\cdots dy\,dx.$$
But *maybe* changing to polar coordinates is convenient.

Comment: I try to change to polar coordinates, how change the integral in this case, i have $\int_T \frac{1}{\rho}\rho d\rho d\theta$ but $-2\le\rho cos\theta\ge 2$ and $\rho^2 cos^2\theta\lt\rho sin\theta\gt 4$

Comment: Sorry, i wrong the verso $-2\le\rho cos\theta\le 2$ and $\rho^2 cos^2\theta\lt\rho sin\theta\lt 4$

Answer (score 0):

You have to integrate over $y$ first with the bounds between $x^2$ and $4$. After that integrate over $x$ with the bounds between $-2$ and $2$.

Comment: I believe that is wrong. The order of the extremes cannot be that.

Comment: @RSerrao Even in your set-up, the *evaluation* of the integral is performed from "inside to outside," so that we integrate over y first, and then, we integrate over x (the outer.)  There was no reason to downvote this answer.